# How to bind spdk driver to NVMe device if root filesystem is mounted there?

Tags: storage, ubuntu-20.04, nvme

I am trying to use `SPDK` in Ubuntu 20.04 (Linux kernel 5.4.0) to run storage applications. My NVMe SSD is allocated as below:

```
$ lsblk
...
nvme0n1                   259:1    0   1.5T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1               259:2    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:3    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:4    0   1.5T  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   200G  0 lvm  /
```

I followed the [getting started](https://spdk.io/doc/getting_started.html) guide from SPDK docs. It is [suggested](https://github.com/spdk/spdk/issues/318) that any filesystem on the device should be unmounted before binding SPDK driver. Since my root (`/`) filesystem is mounted in the device, I ran `umount /` before running `scripts/setup.sh`. It's likely that the SPDK driver does not bind to the NVMe device properly as the example applications like `identify` do not run.  I am not sure if the filesystem is unmounted properly as I still use the shell (`/bin/sh`) after that.

When I try to go back to Linux native kernel driver with `scripts/setup.sh reset`, the nvme device gets a new name `nvme0n2` and the whole filesystem remains read-only. I have to then physically restart the machine again.

How can I use `SPDK` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. Get second NVMe just for test & development.

Answer (score -1):

Got answer from SPDK Slack channel that I cannot bind the SPDK driver to a device with the root filesystem mounted. I either need to have a separate device to contain the root filesystem or use a VM to run SPDK.